# build a map that it's key can be used as srring and array of strings in the same time

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a map that stores an ID for words, something like this:

```
map<string,int> reftag;
int refidcount=0;
string str;
while(cin>>str)
{
    if(reftag[str]==0)
        reftag[str]=++refidcount;
    else
        //This case mean the string is entered more than one time
}
```

The code above would store words only one time, but I need the code to store repeated words more than one time. I want the code to be something like this:

```
typedef vector<string> vstr;
map<vstr,int> reftag;
```

So I would be able to store string more than one time, but I also want to use something like

```
reftag[str]=...
```

to check wheather the word exist or not.

The reason why I want to repeat words is that there is a vector of structs defined to store some informations about each word. and I use the ID of the word to read and modify struct's values.

Comment: are you looking for [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) ?

Comment: Possibly. Statement of the problem is confusing. Can you explain a bit your actual problem, not your current partial solution ?

Comment: *I use the ID of the word* Where does this id come from ?

Comment: Thank you @SanderDeDycker ,this will save a lot of my time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sander De Dycker already stated, `std::multimap` is probably the way to go.

Nevertheless, I want to add that you should never use something like

```
if (map[key]==0) ...
```

If a specified key does not exist in the map, the returned value is of the maps `mapped_type`, but initialized with the default constructor. As for `int`, there is no default constructor defined. On your system it might be that all `int` are zero by default, but on another system this might be different and you code will not work!

Better use

```
if (map.count(key)==0) ...
```

For `std::map` this function returns either 0 or 1, but for `std::multimap` the result can be any integer >=0.